# Update existing shelf in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Can visual studio 2013 update an existing shelf? I have continued to edit my files and now I'd like to update the shelf with my latest version of my current workspace.

Comment: why not just re-shelf to a new shelf set?  It seems like it's intended to be hard to shelf over an existing shelf set since it's not actually change controlled.  Wouldn't want to have shelved something and overwritten it accidentally, thus losing the original shelf set

Comment: Partially because I've already created review requests and I needed to update one of the files in the shelf and I don't want to have to cancel the review, create a new shelf, and re-add all the reviewers. Additionally, it's extremely easy to do this in p4v - so it's a process I'm used to.

Comment: oh and is it visual studio that does the shelf? or is it the source control you're using?  I'm assuming you're using TFS here, but it's not specified - might want to update your tags for better visibility

Comment: source control is tfs, yes, but I'm trying to deal with this via visual studio. I'm asking how this can be done from visual studio (ergo, the tag). I wouldn't be surprised if some tfs client cli could accomplish this, but not my immediate interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Visual Studio Team Suggested on [their forum](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2255761-make-it-easier-to-update-an-existing-shelveset)

> Visual Studio Team (Product Team, Microsoft) responded  ·  March 11,
>   2015 Thanks for the suggestion! We’re currently in the planning
>   process for enabling an iterative shelveset experience. We’ll update
>   this item when we have more details.

But creating a temp workspace, unshelve there, make the desired "update" change, re-shelve with replace can work. Here is a link suggesting it:

[Can you add a file to an existing shelveset](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20773c4f-1a80-4982-b493-299abc05af29/can-you-add-a-file-to-an-existing-shelveset)

Hope it helps further users!!

Answer (score 15):

As it turns out, you can just create a new shelf with the same name and then confirm "Replace shelveset"

Silly tfs.

Comment: Yes, but then that replaces the shelve set. You can not get back to the same state sometimes. For instance, if you were to request a code review, which creates a shelve set, and then check in that code (or some of it) only to find out you needed to make one tiny change? When you go to unshelve the original shelve set it will not have all the files in it anymore because they are checked in. Now when you replace it you replace your change set with JUST the semi-colon you added. Oops.

There are bigger issues with this situation I understand, I'm just trying to make the subtle distinction.