# how to update existing shelve set in tfs

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

My team is using shelving for code review, for X++ code. Which is not a native visual studio language. So you can consider like we storing text files in TFS.

For code developer create a shelve and send it over to the team to reviews it and send feedback. But when the developer address the comments and generates another shelve the comments are lost.

For the reviewer，it becomes difficult if there original comments were addressed or not.  The only way is compare 2 shelve code on 2 screen, which is a pain.

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in code review support that Visual Studio/TFS have? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/get-code-reviewed-vs

Comment: +1 on Wouter de Kort's reply. @Gainster, the Code Review feature in TFS is more suitable for your current 'code review scenario'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update existing shelf in visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424282/update-existing-shelf-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 17):

This function is **not supported** by now.

> *Visual Studio Team (Product Team, Microsoft) responded · March 11,2015*
>
> Thanks for the suggestion! We’re currently in the planning
> process for enabling an iterative shelveset experience. We’ll update
> this item when we have more details.
>
> Source: [VS UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2255761-make-it-easier-to-update-an-existing-shelveset#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)

If you just want to replace the exist shelvest（will lose comment either）, a trick way can be used:  `create a new shelf with the same name and then confirm "Replace shelveset"`

If you want to check the old comment, I suggest you can use [Email Alter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334(v=vs.120).aspx) in TFS. After setting it, you will get a E-mail notification including detail information of the code review. A sample as below:

[image]

---

Updated

Also agreed with Wouter de Kort and Vicky. The biggest advantage of code review in TFS is that you can suspend and resume your work anytime. No need to pay attention to shelvest.