# TFS Java SDK - shelving file that already exists on the repository

Tags: java, tfs, shelve, tfvc, shelveset

I have an application that is uploading a translation to the TFVC repository. We have added two modes of update, check in and shelve. Shelving was supposed to create a file on a shelveset, but we have discovered, that once the same file exists on the repository (it was checked in before), shelvesets are not being created.

It is most likely caused by "gated-build", which is blocking check-in of any *resx files that already exists. It looks like shelvesets are also blocked, if the file already exists in the repsitory.
Could this be a potential reason? Is there a way to avoid this problem using Java SDK or perhaps by changing the configuration on the repository?

On my local-testing TFS repository it works well. We want to create shelvesets everytime on the client server as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update existing shelve set in tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883628/how-to-update-existing-shelve-set-in-tfs)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. All I know is that our client has a gated-build for .resx files. We couldn't upload them directly into the repository, so we had to create a shelvesets. We had this working, but once they've checked in translations, we can no longer replace existing shelveset or even create a new one. I try to reproduce this problem on my local instance of TFS, but it seems to be working here. Is it possible that their configuration is somehow blocking it?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your point. Did you just want to bypass the gated check in? How would you use shelveset to do this ? And why you need to replace the existing shelveset?

Comment: It's not like I want to by pass gated check-in. What I really want is to discover why new shelvesets are not being created on the client TFS repository after the file has been unshelved and checked-in. What we are doing is that we automate the translation process of the files from repository and we upload the translated version back to repo. We have agreed to do that as shelvesets, so we create a shelveset of each file and if the newer version is uploaded, we replace the shelveset with the updated content. Client has unshelved changes and checked them in, the shelvesets are no longer created.