# What is the easiest way to rename a shelveset in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfs-2018

I'm trying to rename a shelveset. The only way I can think of to do it is:

1. Unshelve it (uncheck Preserve shelveset on the server)
2. Gather all the changes into Included Changes (and exclude everything that wasn't part of that shelveset).
3. Re-shelve it with a different name

Is there an easier way?

(we are using TFS Version 15.117.26714.0)

Comment: There is none. You may be able to use the API to create a new Shelveset based on the old one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh717384(v=vs.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to rename a shelveset in TFS?

Personally think the method you think is the simplest or most direct.

Since TFS teams Suggested on their old user voice forum(Closed now):

> Visual Studio Team (Product Team, Microsoft) responded · March 11,
> 2015 Thanks for the suggestion! We’re currently in the planning
> process for enabling an iterative shelveset experience. We’ll update
> this item when we have more details.

But so far, we do not have a very easiest way to rename a shelveset in TFS. And we do not have a "update shelveset" API in place:

[Shelvesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/shelvesets?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Do not have option to rename the name by the [Shelve Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/shelve-command?view=azure-devops).

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883628/how-to-update-existing-shelve-set-in-tfs) for some more details.

So, I agree with your idea is the easiest and most straightforward, and it is also the method I have used.